# I want to run an scons command in my current directory. How do I do this in Java?

Tags: java, command-line

I am using Java to automate a build. I would like to run an 'scons' command **in the current directory** in which the build is being performed. How can I do this with Java? I have tried

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CurrentDir + commandString)`

This didn't work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Getting errors, depsite using ProcessBuilder... java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)... script is in currentDir.

        ... 3 more

Comment: I'm running the build in currentDir which contains the script I need Java to run. Not sure what else to do to correct possible path problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use the Java 5 API [ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to change the current directory for a new process.